# How to install Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-4

As soon as I found out that [Unreal Engine 4 is now free](https://www.unrealengine.com/blog/ue4-is-free), I decided to get it in order to tinker with it.

So I clicked on the blue "*Get Unreal*" button, signed up, and downloaded (and installed) the MSI installer (working on Windows here).

After the installation completed, the "*Epic Games Launcher*" launched, asking me to log in. Once logged in, I selected the "*Unreal Engine*" tab and was greeted by a page with several tutorials and demo projects for download, while the left side offered an orange button saying "*No engine installed*" and no option to click on it to install one.

After some time, I found [this Unreal documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/GettingStarted/Installation/index.html) explaining how to install the engine. According to it, the engine should start downloading the moment I log in to the launcher, which didn't happen.

What am I doing wrong? How can I install the Unreal Engine?

Comment: This question is in the close-vote review queue, flagged as "off-topic"; presumably because it is about installing a program, and not directly about game development. However, the program involved is a game development tool and the question is very specific. I think those are good enough reasons to keep it open.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After spending 10 minutes rummaging through documentations and Google, I finally succeeded in downloading the actual engine.

I was too focused on the orange button in the left pane, that I didn't try clicking on "*Library*", which is where I can choose to download the *Unreal Engine* version of my choice.

Simply click on "*Add Versions*" (hard to miss with its orange + sign) next to "*Engine Versions*". All that's left to do is selecting a version and clicking on the orange "*Install*" button, then wait for the download to complete.

Comment: I had the exact same problem - the orange button is a terrible UI design. The Epic team should, perhaps, poke around the ux.stackexchange.com a bit? ;)

Comment: Me too. I was able to find it only because I noticed this question earlier, so I knew it was hard to find. I didn't remember the answer, but I remembered "yes it's not trivial to find it", and that was motivation enough to keep searching.

Comment: @Shaamaan You get what you pay for.